# date from API in decimal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime

Might not be unrelated, but if you go to this [link](https://convore.com/api/groups/1.json). The date_latest_message is in decimal, how can I convert that to today's date and time in iPhone?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert that double to a human readable date, or how to convert today's date to a double representation similar to the one in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that api uses timestamp for transmitting dates. It seems `+dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` function returns result that looks correct, so parse that decimal value and try the following to get date object:

```
NSTimeInterval creationDate = 1298389881.0542741;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: creationDate];
```

Then you can use `NSDateFormatter` class to format that date to any readable representation you want.